# Unir varios dataframes en un solo fichero

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo varios df

```
structure(list(año = c(2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011), cp = c(22, 
23, 22, 23, 25), tipo = c("verde", "rojo", "amarillo", "azul", 
"azul"), compras = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

structure(list(año = c(2007, 2008, 2016, 2017, 2018), cp = c(32, 
23, 32, 33, 23), tipo = c("morado", "morado", "morado", "morado", 
"morado"), ventas = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

structure(list(año = c(2009, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2022), cp = c(2, 
1, 2, 3, 4), tipo = c("morado", "verde", "morado", "rojo", "amarillo"
), reserva = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Los cargo:

```
df1 <- read_excel("df1.xls")
df2 <- read_excel("df2.xls")
df3 <- read_excel("df3.xls")
```

Hay algunas columnas en común, las uno por esas columnas:

```
df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = c("año","cp","tipo")) -> union

union %>% 
  full_join(df3, by = c("año","cp","tipo")) -> union2
```

y lo guardo todo en xls:

```
write.csv( union2 , 'union2.xls', quote = F,row.names = FALSE)
```

Si en vez de 3 df, tengo 300, ¿cómo lo hago en bucle?

Podría leer los ficheros así:

```
lista1 <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls")   
lista <- lapply(lista1, read_excel)
```

pero a la hora de unirlos me pierdo.

Answer (score 2):

Si tienes una lista con todos los data frames, podrías unirlos todos así:

```
lista <- list(df1, df2, df3)

union <- lista[[1]]

columnas <- c("año", "cp", "tipo")

for (i in 2:length(lista)) {
  union <- union %>%
    full_join(lista[[i]], by = columnas)
}
```

Con tus datos de ejemplo no tiene mucho sentido unirlos de esta forma, por lo que revisa bien si es la forma que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Al menos viendo los datos del ejemplo, entiendo que esto es lo que estarías buscando:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

list.files(path = ".", pattern = 'df.*[.]xls', full.names=TRUE) %>%
  map_df(read_excel)
```

Si bien, técnicamente no es un `join`, tal como están los datos, tampoco estarías haciendo un `join` sino más bien un `union` o un `bind_rows()`, que, mediante `map_df` logramos lo mismo de una forma mucho más compacta. Si hay grupos que se repiten en cada `data.frame` simplemente, al fina deberías agrupar los datos y elegir un criterio para sumarizar, por ejemplo:

```
list.files(path = ".", pattern = 'df.*[.]xls', full.names=TRUE) %>%
  map_df(read_excel) %>% 
  group_by(año, cp, tipo) %>% 
  summarise_all(max)
```